# How to get files from Project Explorer and Package Explorer to new View on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I created wizard to create project and from that project I can create new file or import one. this file shows in Project Explorer and Package Explorer and I can open the file from there. what I want that this file opens a new View and It opens from there. because this file which what you can suggest me? which way?

Comment: what do you mean "opens a new view" ?

Comment: I mean that when I click on the file to open it. it opens editor but what  I need that it opens a new view( like open new Navigator...) not editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse framework can only invoke an editor when you open a file from a navigator view.  However, you can build a read-only editor that looks and acts like a view and let your users open files with this editor.